# React-router-dom + Suspense : Problem in gh-pages deployment

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, github-pages, react-suspense

I am working on a React app which uses **react-router-dom** for routing alongside **React.lazy()** and **Suspense** for code-splitting.

It is the **same gh-pages giving 404 error** problem everyone had and when I encountered it before this, adding the basename prop to the BrowserRouter component would work. However, **even after adding the basename prop**, if I go to a certain route and refresh, the 404 page appears. Also if I directly access a route through the Browser, the 404 appears again.

My **current workaround** is to use **HashRouter** instead of BrowserRouter which doesn't let the app break in production. However, it puts hashes into the routes. Has anyone made the BrowserRouter work with Suspense in deployment on gh-pages or on any other deployment service? A suggestion for a better deployment option for the app is welcome.

Here are my routes in code and an example illustrating the issue:

```js
import React, {Suspense} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Fallback from "./components/Fallback"

const Carousel = React.lazy(()=>import("./components/carousel/Carousel"))
const Home = React.lazy(()=>import("./components/Home"))

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router basename="/home">
        <Suspense fallback={Fallback()}>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/carousel" component={Carousel} />
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, if I go to the deployed site, (say URL: .github.io/home) I see the home page at /. Now if a link takes me to the /carousel route, I can see the carousel page but if I refresh, there are the 404 pages. Also if I directly access /carousel, the 404 pages again. I would love a workaround other than HashRouter which I'm already using.

Comment: I used `Suspence`, `lazy` with `BrowserRoute` and I didn't found any problem like that, I am thinking that you are getting it because of sub route?

Comment: Did you add that route in your homepage field in `package.json`?

Comment: @NishargShah Yes, I have put the whole url in the homepage field along with the base-route

Comment: I think this started when I put the fallback into its own separate component and had to pass `Fallback()` to the fallback prop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest deploying SPAs to gh-pages.

If you want a better service I would suggest using Netlify.

Go ahead and deploy your app it is really easy, I am sure that your problem will disappear.

[www.netlify.com](http://www.netlify.com)

Comment: I tried deploying it to netlify already but that had the exact same issues. It has it's own 404 page that shows up.